# using scala/lift and gwt for RIA

Tags: javascript, scala, gwt, lift

I know there are hundreds of questions towards web development and many of these cover scala and lift. However that's just the reason for my question:

you could skip this background information:

I'm planning on putting up a simple website. I don't have much time for this and its rather a personal playgroung than a real project. Since I'm a huge fan of scala I figured it would be great to use it for the project. No need to tell me that this means work but there's no deadline. Now I only have to decide which framework to use. I have looked into lift and play and various javascript libraries. The final outcome is: I prefer lift over play because it is -in my humble opinion- more "scalaish". I still need something to get the client side pleasant to look at. Therefore I was very happy when I heard about scala support for gwt. I've already took a glimpse at gwt but there's so much out there that I really got no time for trying it all out. The possibility to avoid programming in javascript itself is (at least to me) very appealing. So I decided to search for some opinions gwt.

I found this question:
[Which is better framework Java/GWT or Scala/Lift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948067/which-is-better-framework-java-gwt-or-scala-lift)

Up to now I thought gwt only produced javascript and was therefore strictly client-side. Can I mix the gwt and lift? Is this a good idea or likely to produce "dirty" code. I don't want to get everything messed up with too powerful frameworks. Hopefully you get my meaning.

If you have bad experience with either of them or some good advice how to get going, I'd appreciate it if you'd let me know.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lift as a rest server. And then use gwt for the client side. Keep in mind that the scala gwt is in early stages, and evolving. You may want to look into the java gwt.

You mentioned your preference for not writing javascript, but if that changes, you can use something like jQueryUI to make it look pretty.